# How to start/stop a mule project dynamically on run-time?

Tags: groovy, mule

I am new to **mulesoft**. I have a requirement to restart the project at a certain time everyday. Basically I need to write a cronJob/scheduler which will restart the mule project dynamically at run-time. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** If your application is running in *CloudHub*, then you can use CloudHub API to start or stop your applications. Write a script to invoke following REST API endpoint, and run this script as per your requirement.

- **CloudHub API Documentation:** [Click Here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/apis/8617/versions/2321502/pages/107964)
- **API To Use:** POST /applications/{domain}/status

**Option 2.** If your application is running in *Standalone Server*, then you can write a script to start and stop your applications, and run this script as per your requirement. [Click Here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb) for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Which deployment environment you are using for e.g. CloudHub or standalone mule run-time server. If it is standalone mule server then you can write batch script for Windows or shell script for Linux to start, stop, or restart your mule application by using below commands.

mule start|stop|restart

Comment: I will be have to deploy in some server